# My break statement doesn't break the for loop

Tags: c++

I am working on some code for an assignment. Everything is going good, except I have an issue when trying to break a for loop. I have the following code:

```
//check top
            if (n[i][j] == blank)
            {
                if (i - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    if (n[i - 1][j] == enemyPiece)
                    {
                        for (int a = i - 2; a >= 0; a--)
                        {
                            if (n[a][j] == ourPiece)
                            {
                                possibleMovesList[0].push_back(i);
                                possibleMovesList[1].push_back(j);
                                possibleMovesList[2].push_back(2);
                                out << "Yes -> Case 2" << " r = " << a << " c = " << j << endl;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (n[a][j] == blank)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So the break is supposed to break us out of the for loop so that the code can continue on later with different row and column values. This works on every other case of mine except this one. I set up a dummy out put and it will print the first cases fine, and then this one forever. I couldn't see anything as to why it wont break the for loop, so hoping some experienced programmers can help me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: aside:  `if ((n[i][j] == blank) && (i - 1 >= 0) &&...` will get rid of lots of tabs for you

Comment: Oh, i forgot to mention that I am unable to use a debugger because of an interface .exe that professor has provided

Comment: I believe there are online programs where you can compile and debug c++ code such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4asdMekPdg), just copy/past your code there and step through it

Comment: There is simply not enough context to answer this question. Either provide a minimal sample program that reproduces the effect or debug it by hand (whether via a debugger or copious output messages).

Comment: You can still step through it with pen and paper and brain

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, you can always insert temporary calls to printf() (or cout<<"blah"<<endl;) into your code and then see what the program prints out.  By seeing which ones get printed and which ones do not, you can see where the flow of execution did and did not go.

Answer (score 0):

`break` will exit the loop. Therefore, the conditions `(n[a][j] == ourPiece)` and `(n[a][j] == blank)` are never being seen.  Your guard condition on the `for (a >= 0)` is never triggered because variable `a` is a signed integer which always decreases, and apparently starts negative.

Indexing on negative integers is rarely correct.